# Select on Northwind database using JPA and JDBC Template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I would like to perform select statement on `Northwind` database like this bellow.

```
select distinct b.*, a.CategoryName
from Categories a
inner join Products b on a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
where b.Discontinued = 'N'
order by b.ProductName;
```

I have two problems regarding this operation :

- I have created POJO for tables categories and products like bellow

**Table Products**

```
@Entity
public class Products {
  @Id
  private Long productid;
  private String productname;
  private Long supplierid;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "categories", referencedColumnName = "categoryid")
  private Categories categoryid;
  private String quantityperunit;
  private Double unitprice;
  private Long unitsinstock;
  private Long unitsonorder;
  private Long reorderlevel;
  private String discontinued;
```

**Table Categories**

```
@Entity
public class Categories {
  @Id
  private Long categoryid;
  private String categoryname;
  private String description;
  private String picture;
```

Now I have no idea how to write rowmapper for this tables (please find below ????)

```
private static final RowMapper<Products> productsRowMapper = (rs, rowNum) ->{
        Products products = new Products();
        products.setProductid(rs.getLong("ProductID"));
        products.setProductname(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        products.setSupplierid(rs.getLong("SupplierID"));
        products.setCategoryid(rs.?????
        products.setQuantityperunit(rs.getString("QuantityPerUnit"));
        products.setUnitprice(rs.getDouble("UnitPrice"));
        products.setUnitsinstock(rs.getLong("UnitsInStock"));
        products.setUnitsonorder(rs.getLong("UnitsOnOrder"));
        products.setReorderlevel(rs.getLong("ReorderLevel"));
        products.setDiscontinued(rs.getString("Discontinued"));
        return products;
    };
```

- the second problem is that I don't know if the annotations on the column categoryid in the table products are correct?

---

After correction

```
   @Repository
public class JdbcProductsDao implements ProductsDao{

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcProductsDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    private static final RowMapper<Products> productsRowMapper = (rs, rowNum) ->{
        Products products = new Products();
        products.setProductid(rs.getLong("ProductID"));
        products.setProductname(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        products.setSupplierid(rs.getLong("SupplierID"));
        products.setCategoryid(new Categories(rs.getString("CategoryName")));
        products.setQuantityperunit(rs.getString("QuantityPerUnit"));
        products.setUnitprice(rs.getDouble("UnitPrice"));
        products.setUnitsinstock(rs.getLong("UnitsInStock"));
        products.setUnitsonorder(rs.getLong("UnitsOnOrder"));
        products.setReorderlevel(rs.getLong("ReorderLevel"));
        products.setDiscontinued(rs.getString("Discontinued"));
        return products;
    };


    public Products findByProductName(String productname) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductName = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, productsRowMapper, productname);
    }

    public List<Products> sortByProductName(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM products order by ProductName asc";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, productsRowMapper);
        }
```

**Table Categories**

```
@Entity
public class Categories {
  @Id
  private Long categoryid;
  @Column(name = "CategoryName")
  private String categoryname;
  private String description;
  private String picture;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryid")
  private List<Products> products;
```

**Table Products**

```
   @Entity
public class Products {
  @Id
  private Long productid;
  @Column(name = "ProductName")
  private String productname;
  private Long supplierid;
  @ManyToOne
  private Categories categoryid;
  private String quantityperunit;
  private Double unitprice;
  private Long unitsinstock;
  private Long unitsonorder;
  private Long reorderlevel;
  private String discontinued;
```

---

[image: CategoryName]

Comment: please focus on one subject per question don't edit your question to set a new error, i suggest to create a new question instead!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I have no idea how to write rowmapper for this tables (please find
>   below ????)

You have to set an Object like this :

```
products.setCategoryid(new Categories(rs.getString("a.categoryname"));
```

<sub>I assume you have an constructor `Categories(String categoryname)`</sub>

**Note :** If you want to get more information, you have to change your query and your constructor as well.

---

> the second problem is that I don't know if the annotations on the
>   column categoryid in the table products are correct?

I think there are no need to use `@JoinColumn(name = "categories", referencedColumnName = "categoryid")` just use :

```
@ManyToOne
private Categories categoryid;
```

In your Categories entities add this :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryid")
List<Products> products;
```

Comment: I do as you mentioned but now I have error like bellow "Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'products0_.categoryid_categoryid' in 'field list'"

Comment: next error on the way "Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM products WHERE productname = ?]; SQL state [S0022]; error code [0]; Column 'categoryname' not found.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'categoryname' not found."

Comment: ok @jocom to avoid error like this you can use `@Column(name="CategoryName") private String productname;` for all the attributes note you have to use the same name in database

Comment: Please look at my update above. Can you also explain why should I put @Column(name="CategoryName") above private String productname;

Comment: @jocom you have to use `@Column(name="CategoryName")` in case you are not using the same name of the entity attribute and the table attribute

Comment: After change select statement I see error message as bellow  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcProductsDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID  FROM products WHERE ProductName = ?]; SQL state [S0022]; error code [0]; Column 'CategoryName' not found.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'CategoryName' not found.

Comment: @jocom are you sure you have an attribute `CategoryName` in your table?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I have CategoryName in Categories table

Comment: what rdbms you are using @jocom ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Problem is solved, I changed select statement to `    public Products findByProductName(String productname) {
        String sql = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder, ReorderLevel, Discontinued  FROM products WHERE ProductName = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, productsRowMapper, productname);
    }`